# ./test.ksh[9]: [: argument expected

Tags: arguments, sh, ksh

We are running to script to find the zfs file system monitoring and having error as below.
argument expected

```
#!/bin/sh
USED_SPACE_PERCENT_WARN=20
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin; export PATH
# check zfs File system
if [ `df -F zfs | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
  /usr/sbin/zpool list -H | while read line
  do
    USED_SPACE_PERCENT=`echo "$line" | nawk -F'[    % ]+' '{print $5}'`
    if [ $USED_SPACE_PERCENT -gt $USED_SPACE_PERCENT_WARN ]; then
      POOL=`echo "$line" | nawk -F'[      % ]+' '{print $1}'`
      echo "ZFS pool $POOL has used $USED_SPACE_PERCENT% of its space."
    fi
  done
fi
```

Comment: Check your code with [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: @codeforester shellcheck.net doesn't know about `ksh`, so the results are questionable.

Answer (score 0):

When USED_SPACE_PERCENT is empty (line without 5 fields), the command

```
if [ $USED_SPACE_PERCENT -gt $USED_SPACE_PERCENT_WARN ]; then
```

will turn into

```
if [ -gt 20 ]; then
```

and that causes the error

Comment: Thanks Walter for your help but USED_SPACE_PERCENT is  not empty (line  5 fields)                                                                                                       rpool   596G    279G    317G    46%     1.00x   ONLINE  -
rpool1  1016G   441G    575G    43%     1.00x   ONLINE  -

Comment: Try `set -x` or `echo "USED_SPACE_PERCENT=$USED_SPACE_PERCENT"` or `if [ "$USED_SPACE_PERCENT" -gt 20 ] `